# How to display more than one filter drop-down in the data table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am using the data table to display the list which is working. Now default filter I am getting `Show entries` and `search`.

I have to add one more dropdown for filter called as `role`. If the user chooses "Leader" then it will be filled the record and display in the list.
And

How do I display more than two dropdowns at top instated of the bottom?

Would you help me out in this?

```js
var Table = $('#list').DataTable();
```

```css
.e_list {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<div class="body_wrapper">
  <div class="pad0 m_b_20">
    <div class="e_list">
      <table cellspacing="0" id="list">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Sr.no</th>
            <th> Employee Name </th>
            <th> Mobile No. </th>
            <th> Designation </th>
            <th> Role </th>
            <th> Status </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>mnbv vfgds</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>789654120</td>
            <td>Leader</td>
            <td>Admin</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>poijh</td>
            <td>asdfasd</td>
            <td>789145220</td>
            <td>Employee</td>
            <td>CSR</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn_container  "> </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Here's from the official site: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

Comment: This above link is good but I have to display at top of the header and I have to display more than 2-3 dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list').DataTable( {
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns("4").every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $("#role_menu_placeholder").empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );
 
                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );
 
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
   
               this.api().columns("5").every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $("#status_menu_placeholder").empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );
 
                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );
 
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<div class="body_wrapper">
  <div class="pad0 m_b_20">
  <div>
  <label>Role: </label>
  <span id="role_menu_placeholder"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <label>Status: </label>
    <span id="status_menu_placeholder"></span>
  </div>
    <div class="e_list">
      <table cellspacing="0" id="list">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Sr.no</th>
            <th> Employee Name </th>
            <th> Mobile No. </th>
            <th> Designation </th>
            <th> Role </th>
            <th> Status </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>mnbv vfgds</td>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td>789654120</td>
            <td>Leader</td>
            <td>Admin</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>poijh</td>
            <td>asdfasd</td>
            <td>789145220</td>
            <td>Employee</td>
            <td>CSR</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
           <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th></th>

        <th></th>

        <th></th>

        <th></th>

        <th></th>

        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn_container  "> </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

I came up with this with code from the official documentation for datatables

Comment: Give me some time to understand and implement your answer with my code.

Comment: I just want to kno how to I display drop down at top instated of the bottom?

Comment: I have modified the code to have the menu at the top instead of the bottom. Basically you can create a <div> wherever you want to place the drop down menu and then a span and pass the span id as the param for the ".appendTo" part of the code. In this case I created a span with the id "role_menu_placeholder" and I have passed this id to the .appendTo()

Comment: So is it requires to use <tfoot></tfoot>? What I did, I added columns("4,5") because I have to display both. But it's displaying only one column 4 because of .appendTo( $("#role_menu_placeholder").empty() )

Comment: How do I display both?

Comment: My understanding of your initial question was that you needed this functionality for just the "Roles" column. From your edits, my understanding now is that you need this for both "Roles" and "Status". I have modified my code to work for both "Roles" and "Status". I expect you to understand the basic concept of how this works in other to make any further tweaks to it as desired. I hope my efforts have helped.

Comment: Yes, Because I have to add more in the future. Thanks for the help. upvote from my side.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. For as many more columns you need this for in the future, just create the html list placeholder and then create the JS listener with this.api().columns("xx")....